# xConnect site.xconnect/configuration not found

Tags: xconnect

I've been trying to set up a connection to the xConnect API from a .NET Core website for a couple days now.
I ran in to a bunch of problems and i was wondering if something went wrong with my installation.

In the following 3 lines from the documentation you configure the 3 clients to set up a connection in a non-sitecore context. (https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-client-api/xconnect-client-api-overview/get-client-outside-sitecore.html)

```
        var collectionClient = new CollectionWebApiClient(new Uri("https://first.xconnect/odata"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
        var searchClient = new SearchWebApiClient(new Uri("https://first.xconnect/odata"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
        var configurationClient = new ConfigurationWebApiClient(new Uri("https://first.xconnect/configuration"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
```

When opening the first 2 links (which are the same) i get an empty page which is to be expected and looks fine.
However when opening the last link https://first.xconnect/configuration i get a 404 page not found error. I was wondering if some one could tell me if this is normal.

Comment: This is normal, just checked in my Sitecore 9 environment. Get same HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found error, while xconnect works fine.

Comment: Okay thank you, i'll be posting another question in a half an hour :P